Shade cells in polar plot according to a value
I wrote the following code in Python to make a polar plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

for i in range(30*3):
    if i<30:
        color = "blue"
    else:
        color = choice(['navy','maroon','lightgreen'])
    ax.bar(i * 2 * np.pi / 30, 10/3, width=2 * np.pi / 30, bottom=int(i/30)*(10/3),
           color=color, edgecolor = color)
plt.ylim(0,10)
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()


The most difficult part now is to associate a value (from a list that I have) to each polar cell and shade it according to the value (as in a thermal plot, e.g. from blue to red according to the value). The inner cylindrical cell should not be cut in slices.

looks like you need some color map which does that for you
you can choose one for your liking, example cmap from blue to red is coolwarm but I use a lot of jet because it provides more distinguishable colors in between (green and yellow instead of white)
additionally you need to normalize your color map from 0 to 1 by dividing by max value
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

cmap = matplotlib.colormaps['coolwarm']

list_len = 30*3

for i in range(list_len):
    if i < 30:
        color = cmap(1)
    else:
        color = cmap(i/list_len)
    ax.bar(i * 2 * np.pi / 30, 10/3, width=2 * np.pi / 30, bottom=int(i/30)*(10/3),
           color=color, edgecolor = color)

plt.ylim(0,10)
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()

gives something like this:


just to say don't use jet unless you really have to... it's not colorblind-friendly, and artificially highlights certain value ranges and creates "features" which aren't really there. There are plenty of perceptually uniform choices to use now instead of jet or rainbow colormaps
